# Get definiton scripts of all the (mat)views in a schema at once

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I got a schema with several mat views in it, now I need a simple solution (a SELECT statement for example) to get all the CREATE queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer A. With `pg_catalog.pg_get_viewdef`

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jBe2vkVn1s92xRYCrwS3h3/3

```sql
SELECT 
        c.oid,
        relname,
        n.nspname
        ,format(E'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW \nAS\n%s', pg_catalog.pg_get_viewdef(c.oid)) 
    FROM 
        pg_class c
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON C.relnamespace = n.oid
    WHERE
        relkind='m';
        -- relkind IN ('m', 'v'); - for views too
```

## Answer B. Using `ddlx` extension

I recommend to look on `ddlx` extension: https://github.com/lacanoid/pgddl

It gives niceties as scripting dependencies, support of COMMENTs.

Then your question could be answered as:

```sql
SELECT 
        c.oid,
        relname,
        n.nspname,
        ddlx_create(c.oid) 
    FROM 
        pg_class c
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON C.relnamespace = n.oid
    WHERE
        relkind='m'
        -- relkind IN ('m', 'v'); - for views too
```

Comment: Answer A. and B also gives me this error message: "ERROR:  function ddlx_create(oid) does not exist" but the querie in the fiddle works!

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Look in fiddle for correct variant. Of course `ddlx_create` not exists without install `ddlx`

Comment: Can this include CREATE INDEX and setting permissions as well?

Comment: @STO I encourage you to look on `ddlx`. Honestly I can't live without `ddlx_script`: it creates script of objects **and** all dependent objects, permissions, comments and so on. Which is great when you need to edit a table, than a view, than a fuction that uses view, than a function that returns SETOF. It's a pure SQL extension and of course you can borrow parts of it.